# Find selected data from ArrayList using data provided in HashMap

Tags: java, list, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I have a Product model

```
class Product {

    String name;
    ArrayList<ProductFeature> productFeatures;
}
```

I have a ProductFeature model

```
class ProductFeature {

    String name;
    String value;
}
```

Product Features name-value pairs

1. For name "Color",  value can be [black, red, yellow, etc]
2. For name "Size",   value can be [34, 38, 42, 46, 47, etc]
3. For name "Weight", value can be [10K, 20K, 40K, 41K, etc]

For one name, there will be only one value.
A Product can't have two ProductFeatures with same name.

I have many products, stored in an ArrayList of Product e.g. For Product (feature, feature, feature), I have following data :-

```
e.g. (color, size, weight)

#1 Product ( black,  34, 10.12 )
#2 Product ( yellow, 39, 20.00 )
#3 Product ( black,  67, 22.97 )
#4 Product ( red,    12, 48.21 )
#5 Product ( red,    52, 12.13 )
#6 Product ( blue,   85, 10.00 )*
#7 Product ( blue,   10, 80.00 )
#8 Product ( fire,   87, 40.52 )
```

Back-end says that a product with these features is selected

> [color=blue, size=85, weight=10.00]

I store these features in a `HashMap<String, String>`

```
[
  (color,  blue),
  (size,   85),
  (weight, 10.00)
]
```

I have to find this selected product with these features from my list of products

```
for (Product product : products) {

    ArrayList<ProductFeature> productFeatures = product.getProductFeatures();

    // I am stuck here
}
```

How do I compare this list `productFeatures` with my `HashMap<String, String>` to find out which product from `products` has all the features from HashMap?

If more information is needed, please ask.

Comment: Couple of tips: Don't use implementation classes (ArrayList) for attributes, also you are coding in a statically typed language, take advantage of it instead of using String

Comment: @DPM can you elaborate on this please? Maybe post a link so that I can understand all of your comment.

Comment: For my first point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/383982/1045902 About the second, I mean that if you are going to pay for Java verbosity at least make meaningful classes, or enums instead of strings. But this is opinionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like below:

```
private Product findMatch( List<Product> products, Map<String, String> map )
{

    for (Product product : products) 
    {

        ArrayList<ProductFeature> productFeatures = product.getProductFeatures();

        boolean found = true;
        for ( ProductFeature feature : productFeatures )
        { 
           if ( map.containsKey( feature.name ) && map.get( feature.name ).equals( feature.value ) )
           {
              continue;
           }
           found = false;
           break;
        }

        if ( found ) 
        {
           return product;
        }
    }

    return null;

}
```

But I strongly believe you could improve your design better for better searches.

Comment: This is the approach I needed. Thanks. Keeping in mind that `color`, `size`, `weight` are completely random(there can be any names and any number of names), how can I improve design on my side? I, only, converted received data from Backend into a HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

I highly suggest you go for a completely different design.

```
class Product {
    String name;
    ProductFeature productFeatures;
}

class ProductFeature {
    String color;
    int size;
    double weight;
}
```

Let's say, you want to find a yellow `Product` with the same size and weight of 20. You can simply compare its `ProductFeature` to get the desired one. Of course, don't forget to override the `equals()` method to compare features correctly:

```
ProductFeature compared = new ProductFeature("Yellow", 20, 20.0);
Product returned = null;

for (Product product : products) {
    ProductFeature current = product.getProductFeature;
    if (current.equals(compared) {
        returned = product;
        break;
    }
}

// now the variable 'returned' contains the product that matches the characteristics.
```

Comment: Thanks, but `color`, `size`, `weight` are examples. There can be `ram`, `storage`, `processer`. All of them are dynamic, that's why I used name-value pairs.